PBI DAX Trying to Average a Count (Monthly Avg of Daily Unique Value Count)
(Sorry for using screenshots instead of code blocks - I'm trying to figure out how to get this post past the spam filter)
I have the following which gives me a count of unique values of [Agent Email] by Project / Day:
Sample Code 1
Gives me the following:
Sample Output 1
What I want is to then find the average of that count by Month / Project - so, for this example the output would be:



ProjectMonth
Project
Month
Monthly Agent Count Avg




2/1/2024
Project1
Thursday, February 1, 2024
340



I've tried just wrapping this table code in another Summarize, like follows, but it doesn't recognize the [Agent Count] column I created in the above DAX:
Sample Code 2
This shows the error:
DAX Code Error
